# STRAPI MODEL IN PRODUCTION MODE (PM2 & BUDDY)

Tags: pm2, strapi

My previous models are working right but when I added the interview model it works in development mode but not in production. I'm using pm2 and buddy (CI).

What type of commands I need to pass to pm2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what is your development / production workflow with Strapi but.

1. When you are in you local machine with `development` environment, you have to start your application with `strapi start`. With this command, some feature to restart your app automatically when you create/update/delete content type are available. If you don't use this command you can have some trouble during your development process.
2. When you are done with your development. You have to push all you code in your production server (use the way you want to do that). And then you can start Strapi using pm2 `NODE_ENV=production pm2 start npm --name api -- start`

Note in production you will not have access to the Content Type Builder and Settings Manager (you haven't to update config in production).

Comment: --name api. The 'api' is it the app name?